play sound when flip card in flutter
I want to play sound when the cart flipping to show mean of word to the user I tried with Inkwell but it doesn't work.
I want to implement a dictionary that when the user clicks on any word can see mean and listen voice.
Also, I have placed a button at the bottom of the page to test the sound, when we click on it, the sound will play, but it does not work for the program.
my code repo: https://github.com/efarhadi/sw_flash
my test_filip.dart file:
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TestFlip extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestFlip({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestFlipState createState() => _TestFlipState();
}

class _TestFlipState extends State<TestFlip> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  List _items = [];
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/words.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      _items = data["items"];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    readJson();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      playSound('a070.mp3');
                    },
                    child: _HomeScreenCard(_items[index]["name"],
                        _items[index]["description"], context),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound('a070.mp3');
                },
                child: Text('sala'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _HomeScreenCardFront(String text, context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      // width: 200,
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }

  Widget _HomeScreenCardBack(String text, context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        // color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      // width: 200,
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }

  Widget _HomeScreenCard(String textFront, String textBack, context) {
    return FlipCard(
      fill: Fill.fillBack,
      direction: FlipDirection.HORIZONTAL, // default

      front: _HomeScreenCardFront(textFront, context),
      back: _HomeScreenCardBack(textBack, context),
    );
  }

  playSound(String sound) async {
    await player.play(AssetSource(sound));
  }
}


import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TestFlip extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestFlip({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestFlipState createState() => _TestFlipState();
}

class _TestFlipState extends State<TestFlip> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  List _items = [];
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/words.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      _items = data["items"];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    readJson();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return _HomeScreenCard(_items[index]["name"],
                      _items[index]["description"], context);
                },
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound('a070.mp3');
                },
                child: Text('sala'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _HomeScreenCardFront(String text, context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      // width: 200,
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }

  Widget _HomeScreenCardBack(String text, context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        // color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      // width: 200,
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }

  Widget _HomeScreenCard(String textFront, String textBack, context) {
    return FlipCard(
      onFlipDone: (value){
        playSound('a070.mp3');
      },
      fill: Fill.fillBack,
      direction: FlipDirection.HORIZONTAL, // default

      front: _HomeScreenCardFront(textFront, context),
      back: _HomeScreenCardBack(textBack, context),
    );
  }

  playSound(String sound) async {
    await player.play(AssetSource(sound));
  }
}

replace your code by this, and it should work's as expected
what i did?
the flipCard widget already have a atributte for when the card flips
its' called  onFlipDone:
there you'll set the method to reproduce the sound

thank you :) and another question I want to play sound when the card flips and don't play when it filip back. how can I do it? –

ok,always set the aswer that help you as correct

just need to check the boolean variable  value
if(value)         playSound('a070.mp3');

In your case, the FlipCard widget has a handy function onFlip that is needed by you, not an extra InkWell widget, you should play your sound in there.
...
              ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  // Remove the unneeded InkWell
                  return _HomeScreenCard(_items[index]["name"],
                      _items[index]["description"], context);
                },
              )
...
Widget _HomeScreenCard(String textFront, String textBack, context) {
    return FlipCard(
      fill: Fill.fillBack,
      direction: FlipDirection.HORIZONTAL, // default
      // Use the already-given function here
      onFlip: () async {
        await playSound('a070.mp3');
      },
      front: _HomeScreenCardFront(textFront, context),
      back: _HomeScreenCardBack(textBack, context),
    );
  }
...

To add more spice to this answer, you should name your variables and methods with lowercase lowerCamelCase letters, which is a convention for Dart language. You can, and frankly should, use the underscore before the variable/method if that's meant to be a private one, but the following letter should start with a lowercase.
You can try looking into linters that are useful to learn and apply these cases (try maybe very_good_analysis).

thank you :) and another question I want to play sound when the card flips and don't play when it filip back. how can I do it?

I just deleted the source code and am too tired to try that myself. But that should be an easy check i.e. you make a new bool variable that checks whether card is flipped. If flipped then don't play the sound and else play it. Should be fairly simple with simple flags.

Or as the other user suggested there's a method onFlipDone you check the value that comes from that method and if that's 1 then it's flipped else not flipped, just test it yourself, but that's an even easier solution than my above one.
